# How do I get the scene update handler to break when the action is up (AndEngine)?

Tags: android, handler, andengine

I'm trying to increase the scale of a sprite using an update handler. It doesn't, however, allow for the scene action up event to be called, so the sprite continues increasing in size. How do I get the update handler to break when the action is up? This is what I have:

The update handler:

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {         
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            if(fillerNum>-1){
                if(filler[fillerNum].active){

                    mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(filler[fillerNum].sprite));
                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(filler[fillerNum].body);

                    filler[fillerNum].sprite.setScale(filler[fillerNum].scale+=pSecondsElapsed*3);

                    filler[fillerNum].body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, filler[fillerNum].sprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
                    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(filler[fillerNum].sprite, filler[fillerNum].body, true, true));
                }
            }               
        }
    });
```

And the scene touch event:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
     if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                createFiller(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
                return true;
            }
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
                Log.e("Action UP", Boolean.toString(filler[fillerNum].active));
                createStationaryFiller();
            }
        }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just save the instance of the UpdateHandler:

```
handler = new IUpdateHandler() {... etc
```

and when you want to stop it, call `scene.unregisterUpdateHandler(handler)`

Comment: I thought about this, but my isactionup never registers (the log statement never executes), which is where I'd want to call scene.unregisterUpdateHandler(handler), right?

Comment: Does the TouchEvent even fire when you lift the finger? Put some log output before the if statement and see. Maybe try checking for pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP instead. I don't think it will help but it's worth a try.

Comment: Also, log the values of pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() and tell me what you get.

Comment: No it did not. As it turns out, I needed to and an isactionup() in my onAreaTouch method as well.